Customize the theme/colors Salesforce Survey
I'm trying to find a solution to change the color of the responses and the progress bar of the Salesforce Survey. Is that possible? I changed the theme of the org but it didn't work.
Here's an example: when you click on one of the stars, they turn the standard blue color, but I want to change it to another color.

